# SQL Query To Create View

Tags: mysql, sql, create-view

I have some tables on my database, I am using MySQL

See the image below. It is the simple version of my database

How to create view the user detail?

[image]

Comment: Where **exactly** are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW EmpList
AS
SELECT  a.id_user,
        b.category_province_content,
        c.category_city_content,
        d.category_job_content
FROM    user_detail a
        INNER JOIN category_province b
            ON a.detail_province = b.id_category_province
        INNER JOIN  category_city c
            ON a.detail_city = c.id_category_city
        INNER JOIN category_job d
            ON a.detail_job = d.id_category_job
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins and MySQL views, kindly visit the links below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)
- [MySQL CREATE VIEW Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
create view view1
as 
    select ud.id_user_detail, cp.category_province_content,
    cc.category_city_content, cj.category_job_content 
    from user_detail ud, category_province cp,
    category_city cc, category_job cj 
    where ud.detail_province=cp.id_category_province
    and ud.detail_city=cc.id_category_city
    and ud.detail_job=cj.id_category_job
```